# Regional data transfer charge between EC2 from separated AWS accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

1, if 2 EC2 instances in separated VPC in the same AZ, so they can not connected by private IP right? so BOTH of ec2 will be charged the regional data transfer fee right?

2, said 2 ec2 instances in the same AZ from 2 separated AWS accounts. It is very common case due to lot of servers are from EC2. For example, one ec2 instance is from a 3rd party service provider, and one instance is from me. Even if they are in the same AZ, When my ec2 send/receive data from/to that ec2 from 3rd party, BOTH of us will be charged  regional data transfer fee, right?

3, Is it possible to use private IPs to connect/send traffic between EC2 instances in the same AZ from different accounts?

4, how can I launch a ec2 without VPC?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about the AWS fee structure, not a programming question.

Answer (score 3):

VPCs can be [peered](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html), in which case the instances can communicate via private IP addresses, as long as the CIDR supernets of the VPCs don't overlap.

However, you'll still be charged the regional transfer rate.

There is no such concept as instances from two different AWS accounts being in "the same" availability zone, because this isn't something you can readily determine, and even if you can, it doesn't matter:

> To ensure that resources are distributed across the Availability Zones for a region, we independently map Availability Zones to identifiers for each account. For example, your Availability Zone `us-east-1a` might not be the same location as `us-east-1a` for another account. Note that there's no way for you to coordinate Availability Zones between accounts.
>
> <sup>—http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html</sup>

The charge is always the same, between accounts -- it's regional data transfer, within the region.

Note that both instances are billed $0.01/GB.  The net charge, then, is $0.02/GB, split across the two instances, whether you use private or public IP addresses, the charge is the same whether you use VPC peering or simple connect directly over public IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding questions #2 and #3:

You **can** determine which physical AZs are represented by the logical names assigned within your account. Here is the guidance from AWS:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/use-consistent-availability-zones-in-vpcs-across-different-aws-accounts.html

> This pattern helps ensure zonal consistency by providing a
> cross-account, scalable solution for using the same Availability Zones
> in your subnets. Zonal consistency ensures that your cross-account
> network traffic avoids cross-Availability Zone network paths, **which
> helps reduce data transfer costs** and lower network latency between
> your workloads.